# python numpy set elements of list by condition

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to set a specific element of my list to specific value with low overhead.
for example if I have this : `a = numpy.array([1,2,3,0,4,0])` I want to change every 0 value to 10; in the end I want to have [1, 2, 3, 10, 4, 10]

in Matlab you can do this easily like a(a==0) = 10, is there any equivalent in numpy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remarkably similar to Matlab:

```
>>> a[a == 0] = 10
>>> a
array([ 1,  2,  3, 10,  4, 10])
```

There's a really nice ["NumPy for Matlab Users"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-13d7391dd7e2c57d293809cff080260b46d8e664) guide at the SciPy website.

I should note, this doesn't work on regular Python lists. NumPy arrays are a different datatype that work a lot more like a Matlab matrix than a Python list in terms of access and math operators.

Answer (score 1):

A little more pythonic way would be like this, I guess:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([1,2,3,0,4,0])
for k,v in enumerate(a):
    if v == 0:
        a[k] = 10
print a
```

Even more pythonic way (provided by @mtrw)

```
[10 if k == 0 else k for k in a]
```

Comment: I'd argue an even more Pythonic way would be `[10 if k == 0 else k for k in a]`, but this is exactly the difference between NumPy arrays and Python lists.

Comment: why would you do this instead of the mask indexing in the other example?  im sure there are use-cases (more complex conditional etc).